# Is wordpress caching widgets?

Tags: wordpress

I have to move a wordpress site under an other domain (foo.com => foo.hu) so it's needed to update the links on the site. I wrote a script which replaces the tld in the database in the posts/options, but when I check the site I see no widgets on the sidebar...

I tried to find something about it's caching (based on md5 hash or like that), because if I replace the tld to the original in the text widget everything is fine again. But regarding to the wordpress documentation (and some forums) there's no permanent caching built in.

So my question is, how can I modify the contents of text widget from the outside?

I really don't want to do it by hand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the widgets is a serialized DB entry. So if the new domain name has a different string length than the old domain name, the serialized DB entry (as well as any other serialized DB entry that includes a domain name, such as attachment URLs, etc.) will become malformed.